# countries covered by a GPS trace

Tags: gps, here-api

I have a GPS trace and I wish to find out which countries does this trace effectively span. In other words if I go over the trace from beginning to end which countries does the trace go over.
Is there an API call which can help me accomplish this task?

with kind regards

Rohit

Comment: You can program it. you have the country shapes, and "just" check in which country the starting point is in. Probably an API is more complex (but you can program it)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to program it yourself:

1. Download the rough country borders as polygons in latitude longitude format (WGS84). (There are stackoverflow answers on this topic)
2. for each coordinate of the GPS trace call a "point-in-polygon" algorithm, where each country is represented as one polygon. You might want to ignore special situations like enclaves. (That would be a country polygon with holes)